# How to fix style in IE for dropdown list?

Tags: css

I have this dropdown list but problem is when i run it in IE it goes up and down if i select something from bottom or middle.How can fix so that it expand it always bellow:
https://jsfiddle.net/tq1bhfno/ (you need to run it in IE)

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">

    <div class="select-wrapper">
        <select name="gametype" id="gametype" ng-model="selectGameType">
          <option>TEST1</option>
          <option>TEST2</option>
          <option>TEST3</option> 
          <option>TEST4</option>
          <option>TEST5</option>
          <option>TEST6</option>
          <option>TEST7</option>


        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just ran it in ie and it runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

Drop-downs are rendered by the Browser/OS. You cannot control this type of behaviour using CSS or JavaScript.

#### What about the dropdown itself?

As in, the thing that shows the choices when activated. As far as I know, there is no way to style these in any browser. Not even bold or italic. The closest thing to style you can get is grouping them by using . This is probably mostly a UI thing, but it might be a security thing too. You wouldn't want people doing tricky things with fonts that make it unclear what option is selected.

[Read More About Dropdown Default Styling](https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/)

See the behavior without any CSS:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/tq1bhfno/2/
```

Only the HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">

<div class="select-wrapper">
    <select name="gametype" id="gametype" ng-model="selectGameType">
      <option>TEST1</option>
      <option>TEST2</option>
      <option>TEST3</option> 
      <option>TEST4</option>
      <option>TEST5</option>
      <option>TEST6</option>
      <option>TEST7</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

It is the same.

Comment: yes, exactly the same no problems. Check my solution below

Comment: choose test 6 and then click again...it expands over dropdown in IE

Answer (score 0):

```
bottom: 100%;
```

add this attribute to your css for dropdown. This forces to show everything below.

Comment: and get rid of top: 50%;

Comment: can u update fiddle where to put it because i get same result when i get rid top:50%;

Comment: @pokrak94 and nothing will happen

Comment: just linking it now two seconds :) checked it and works for me.

Comment: i get same result again :(

Comment: @None and the reason for that is in my answer :)

Comment: @IlanHasanov so there is no way to fix that?

Comment: my bad, did not realize I was testing in chrome first time round. I think Ilan is right.